# Parsing a Rss feed from a hebrew news site

Tags: xml, rss

im building a news app that parses an Israeli news site (Hebrew) , I keep getting this Error "org.apache.harmony.xml.expatparser$parseexception at line 1 column 17 not well-formed (invalid token)"
now i know that the problem is in the encoding ...the encoding in the rss feed is "Windows-1255",
the rss feed "view-source:http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss2.xml" 
i tried :

```
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    RssHandler rh = new RssHandler();
    input= new InputSource(new StringReader(feed));
    input.setEncoding("Windows-1255");
    sp.parse(input, rh);
```

but its not working ....
please help me ! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How did you read the feed to a String? The xml probably broke there because this seems to work with no errors on my Linux machine(UTF8 charset by default) with Oracle's Java 8 :

```
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        InputSource input = new InputSource(new URL("http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss2.xml").openStream());
        sp.parse(input, new DefaultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                System.out.print(qName + ": ");
            }
            @Override
            public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                System.out.print(new String(ch, start, length));
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

"org.apache.harmony.xml.expatparser$parseexception".. Are you using Apache Harmony? It's an outdated Java implementation, try updating to something newer if possible. I also suggest using [Rome](http://rometools.github.io/rome/) for reading rss feeds.